# How to delay a formula to be shown for a certain number of hours?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013. In cell D5 I have my date of birth, in cell E5 I have a formula that recognizes if today is my birthday and if it is, it shows `YES`, if not `NO`. Now the formula works great BUT the formula MUST NOT show `YES` before 10 a.m.!

How can I delay that formula so it only shows `YES` if it's past 10am?

I'm not doing this in VBA because I've got a task to write a formula! Here's the formula:

```
=IF(TEXT(D5;"d.m.")=TEXT(TODAY();"d.m.");"YES";"NO")
```

Please can someone write me the delayed formula or tell me what function I should use to delay that formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you only want to show "YES" from 10:00 until midnight on that day?

You could possibly use `HOUR` function in conjunction with your current formula, e.g.

`=IF(AND(TEXT(D5;"d.m.")=TEXT(TODAY();"d.m.");HOUR(NOW())>=10);"YES";"NO")`

or perhaps simpler to use `DATEDIF` for your current date comparison like this:

`=IF(AND(DATEDIF(D5;TODAY();"yd")=0;HOUR(NOW())>=10);"YES";"NO")`

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED but please try:

```
=IF(NOW()-TODAY()<10/24;"";"YES")
```

(Needs refreshing.)